How to update a JSON file (Not only JSON Model) in SAPUI5?
I have a SAPUI5 application where I have a JSON file users.json under my models like this:
{"name":"John"}

I want to update the JSON file like this on a button click
{"name":"John, Joe"}

Using this.getOwnerComponnet().setModel() is updating the model only, not the actual "users.json" file. I want to update the json file also.
Can anyone help in updating the actual users.json file?

Without the use of File System Access API*, browsers do not allow any direct manipulation of local files. The JSONModel in SAPUI5 is rather meant to store client-side data temporarily during the lifecycle of the app, not to persist the data locally.

* Currently only supported partially by Chromium browsers. See also https://caniuse.com/native-filesystem-api.
